# Find $\nabla \|x^HAx - b\|_2^2$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have to find- $$\nabla\|x^HAx - b\|_2^2,$$ where $x$ is a vector and $A$ is a $4\times 4$ hermitian matrix. I am trying to solve it by using identities given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus but I am not able to figure out which identity suits my problem. I would appreciate if anyone tells me how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Write out the norm explicitly and then take partial derivatives.

Comment: After writing out norm explicitly, the problem will reduce to $\nabla(x^HAx - b)^2$. Which identity do I need to use from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus to proceed further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\nabla_x\|x^HAx - b\|_2^2 = \nabla_x(x^HAx - b)^2=4(x^HAx - b)Ax$$

Comment: Thanks. In case I have the same problem with $ \nabla_x\sum_{k=1}^{180}|x^HA_kx - b_k\|_2^2$ , will the gradient still be the same?

Comment: Yes because $x$ is independent of $k$. Answer in that case will be-$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} 4(x^H A_k x - b_k)A_k x$.

Comment: thanks! Will its second order derivative be $4((x^HAx - b)A + 2A^2x^2)$?

Comment: No. That will be completely separate story. Also what do you mean by squaring a vector- $x^2$?

Comment: I found the second order derivative as $4((x^HAx-b)A + 2Ax(Ax))$. I used the product rule of differentiation.

Comment: Isn't this the correct way of doing so? I would appreciate if you could provide any suggestion on solving this as I am not much familiar with calculus stuff!

Comment: I think the answer is correct, when $b= b^*$, otherwise the gradient should be $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^*} \left\|x^H A x - b \right\|_2^2= 2 A x \left( 2x^H A x - (b + b^*)\right)$.